# Excel Countif different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have this table

```
     A   B 
  1 blue red
  2 blue blue
  3 red blue
  4 red red
```

How do I count the rows where A<>B in Excel? (in the example there are 2)

I tried several ways of SUMIF(A2:B250;"A2<>B2") but nothing worked so far

Comment: So show what you have tried, sumifs(0 or sumproduct(0 can work.

Comment: Right, just edited my post.

Comment: `=COUNTIF($A$2:$B$250, "<>"&$B$2:$B$250)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<>B1:B4))
```